# Calculating percentage shares with RxJava

Tags: rx-java

Suppose I have the following data:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
counts.put("one", 1);
counts.put("two", 2);
counts.put("three", 3);
```

I would like to output the % per category, something like:

```
one: 1/6 = 0.17
two: 2/6 = 0.33
three: 3/6 = 0.5
```

How can I compute the percentage share of each category efficiently with RxJava?

> Note that this is a contrived example, where it is not trivial to reprocess the source data (which actually already comes to me as an Observable).

Many thanks for any help you can offer,
Dan.

**Things I've tried so far**

The problem I run into is that with my set of Observables I always need to go back and reprocess the individual categories after I have merged them to calculate the total. I've tried publish and using subjects for this purpose, but in each case the need to calculate the total (i.e. blocking) before calculating the percentages means that my .connect() or onNext()s never run.

Comment: Since you must calculate the total before emitting any data, you can call `toMap` to collect all data from `Observable` and then calculate the percentages for all categories. At last, emit percentages for all categories one by one.

Comment: would you mind phrasing the question in terms of streams? I'm not sure if you are streaming maps or the items in the map. Do you want Observable.just("one",one","two") to yield a single Map on completion with the percentages or do you want a Map after each emission with percentages so far?

Comment: @DaveMoten Hi! In the real example, I'm streaming records and grouping them by. I would like to know the % representation of each group. Ideally this would be then streamed out again as I want to calculate a weighted average of the averages computed here but I don't image that to be problematic. I do not need to go via maps per se, it was just a convenient way to represent the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below takes the stream {"one", "two", "one"} and outputs:

```
WithPercent [value=one, percent=66.66666666666667]
WithPercent [value=two, percent=33.333333333333336]
```

runnable class:

```
import rx.Observable;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Observable.just("one", "two", "one")
                .groupBy(x -> x)
                .flatMap(g -> g.count()
                        .map(n -> new WithCount<String>(g.getKey(), n)))
                // now get a list of the counts by key
                .toList()
                // iterate the list and get totals, calculate percents and emit
                .flatMap(list -> {
                    int total = list.stream().mapToInt(wc -> wc.count).sum();
                    return Observable.from(list).map(
                            wc -> new WithPercent<String>(wc.value, 100.0 * wc.count / total));
                }).subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static class WithCount<T> {
        final T value;
        final int count;

        WithCount(T value, int count) {
            this.value = value;
            this.count = count;
        }
    }

    private static class WithPercent<T> {
        final T value;
        final double percent;

        WithPercent(T value, double percent) {
            this.value = value;
            this.percent = percent;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "WithPercent [value=" + value + ", percent=" + percent + "]";
        }

    }
}
```